# Google Chrome trouble installing plug-in message

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, plugins

Recently the Google Chrome browser has been prompting me to install a plug-in every time I visit a web page. I always say Yes, install plug-in, but that seems to have no effect. I tried following the "Trouble installing plug-ins" on the Chrome toolbar, but that seems to say Windows Media Player is the problem, but again, all my attempts at installing don't have any effect.

As far as I know, I have not changed anything, but Skype did recently upgrade itself.

This is Windows 7 Professional 64-bit, and Chrome says it is up-to-date. I'm going to run a malware checker next, just in case -

Thanks!

(Figured this out - but my rep here is too low to self-answer so quickly -so here's the answer, cause I don't want to wait)

Ok - pretty sure I figured this out - I uninstalled Chrome, then re-installed. Then I went to www.cnn.com and got the same "plugin needed" prompt, BUT, when I closed chrome, a message popped up saying "Windows is configuring Skype Click-to-Call". After that, I started Chrome again, went to www.cnn.com - and message is gone.

Sooo.... for now - I am going to blame Skype click-to-call (and Chrome for giving misleading error messages)

Thanks guys!

Comment: What plug-in are you trying to install?

Comment: Thanks wizlog - How can I tell? The message just says "An additional plug-in is required to display some elements on this page." I click "Install plug-in" - but no change

Comment: @Jeff you should be able to self answer now - please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - pretty sure I figured this out - I uninstalled Chrome, then re-installed. Then I went to www.cnn.com and got the same "plugin needed" prompt, BUT, when I closed chrome, a message popped up saying "Windows is configuring Skype Click-to-Call". After that, I started Chrome again, went to www.cnn.com - and message is gone.

Sooo.... for now - I am going to blame Skype click-to-call (and Chrome for giving misleading error messages)

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this [help article](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95697), it might help you in fixing the problem?

> 1. Visit http://port25.technet.com/pages/windows-media-player-firefox-plugin-download.aspx
> 2. Click Download Now.
> 3. Click Save for the file in the downloads bar to confirm that you want to download the file. Don't worry -- saving the file won't harm
>      your computer. Learn more about [downloading files](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95759) in Google Chrome.
> 4. Open the set-up file.
> 5. Click Run to start the Setup Wizard. Follow the instructions in the wizard to finish installing the plugin.
> 6. Restart Google Chrome.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep - I followed all those instructions - installed the media player plugin, and re-insatlled the java plugin, and re-booted the machine for good luck. No change. I guess I'm the only one having this problem. Back to IE for me - maybe I will try uninstall and re-install Chrome - thanks anyway